# Omitting Scientific Notation in Numeric columns when working with Dynamic SQL returning JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, dynamic, dynamicquery, for-json

The below dynamic query returns the output of the numeric columns in Scientific notation.

```
DECLARE @Cols VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT STUFF((
SELECT ',' +'['+ Description + ']' FROM @PermittedColumnIDs

DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TOP 1000 '+ @Cols +' FROM ' + (SELECT ViewName FROM
@DynamicQueryProps) + ' FOR JSON AUTO';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

JSON output

[image: JSON]

Tabular output

[image: Table]

As above mentioned, tabular view returns the `AWP` value properly and JSON view returns it with the scientific notation. **How to get the JSON `AWP` column without Sc. notation.**

Please note that

- It needs to preserve the numeric value as numeric without converting it to a string in the JSON result.
- Cannot change the format of individual columns since columns are dynamic.

Comment: Probably `AWP`column is a `float` column. What is the information stored in the `@PermittedColumnIDs` table?

Comment: Just the column name

Comment: One possible approach is to use `CONVERT(numeric(x, y), Description) AS Description` when you dynamically generate the `SELECT` statement for each `float` column. The only part from the documentation about how `FOR JSON` converts SQL Server data types to JSON types is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-converts-sql-server-data-types-to-json-data-types-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and there is no information about the format that is used for this conversion.

Comment: What if the dynamically selected column's data type is VARCHAR? Isn't this function tries to convert it also to a numeric?

Comment: No, only the `float` columns will be converted to numeric.

Comment: `DECLARE @Cols VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT STUFF((
        SELECT ',' +'['+ s.Description + '] AS [' + REPLACE(s.Description, ' ', '') + ']'
        FROM @PermittedColumnIDs s
        ORDER BY s.ID FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')) `

Could you please show me how to apply the above code segment in here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too long for a comment, so I post this as an answer. I'm able to find only these explanations in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/how-for-json-converts-sql-server-data-types-to-json-data-types-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) about how `FOR JSON` converts SQL Server data types to JSON types. So, as a possible workaround, you may try to convert the `float` columns to `numeric` using information from system catalog views (I assume, that the `SELECT` is against a view).

```
DECLARE @cols varchar(MAX) = STUFF(
    (
    SELECT 
        ', ' +
        CASE 
           WHEN t.[name] = 'float' THEN 'CONVERT(numeric(10, 2), [' + p.[description] + ']) AS [' + p.[description] + N'] '
           ELSE p.[description] 
        END
    FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.views v ON c.object_id = v.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON v.schema_id = s.schema_id
    JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
    JOIN @PermittedColumnIDs p ON p.[description] = c.[name]
    WHERE v.[name] = (SELECT ViewName FROM @DynamicQueryProps) AND s.[name] = 'dbo'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''
)

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) 
SET @query = 
   N' SELECT TOP 1000 '+ @Cols +
   N' FROM [' + (SELECT ViewName FROM @DynamicQueryProps) + ']' +
   N' FOR JSON AUTO';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```